# JavaFX Как передать пользователя в другой контроллер

Tags: java, javafx, desktop

Суть заключается в том, что у меня есть контроллер сцены авторизации/регистрации, где юзер вводит свой логин, пароль и т.д. после успешного входа открывается новое окно с новым контроллером. В данный контроллер необходимо передать всю информацию о пользователе(Логин, почту, и другие данные из базы данных именно этого юзера). Как мне организовать передачу?

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте информацию по ссылке, должно помочь https://code.makery.ch/ru/library/javafx-tutorial/part3/

Автор статьи создал две сцены, у каждой свой контролер, информация из одной сцены передается в observerList, связанный с другим контролером.